# This Riddle's Answer is Missing

Tags: riddle

Ideally if you pressure me I will not break, 
alas, my weakness seems to come at my weakest. 
But if you truly press me I will show you the way, 
However afterwards I may be a little flushed. 
 
If you are looking for a connection that will be me, 
On down the chain, each step of the way. 
Especially when I get worked up and excited, 
press me I will show you the way.

> Sorry for the lack of details but the rest of my hints are currently in the too easy/production state, more will probably come in roughly ~17 hours if no one gets it before then. I kind of enjoy its current state. <sub>[Message out of date but extremely accurate of what happened]</sub>

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too broad" because most of the answers seem to fit the clues very well, even if they aren't what the OP intended.

Comment: @CodeNewbie I don't think we've seen a complete fit so far; most answers are pretty tenuous for at least one line. Player One has a good one, but even then the final line isn't quite explained. Well, we'll see!

Comment: Yeah, I will add more  lines in an hour or two. Each has at least one line that leaves me a little confused but I clearly need to add some of the easier hints...

Comment: You said the answer is missing... is the answer "missing"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is it

> A link

Ideally if you pressure me I will not break,

> Hopefully a link in the chain won't break if you put pressure on it

alas, my weakness seems to come at my weakest.

> Weakest link

But if you truly press me I will show you the way,

> A hyperlink will take you to another place

However afterwards I may be a little flushed.

> Hyperlinks change color after they've been clicked on.

If you are looking for a connection that will be me,

> A connection can also be thought of as a link

On down the chain, each step of the way.

> A chain has links in it

Especially when I get worked up and excited,

> Hyperlinks are Hyper links

press me I will show you the way.

> A hyperlink will take you to another place

The Riddle's answer is missing

> The missing link as in the missing link in human evolution

Comment: Being flushed may be a reference to hyperlinks often changing color after they are clicked.

Comment: @Lampost42 that makes a lot more sense than my answer. I was kind of stretching mine to find something that fit

Comment: One thought, you might want to change the worked up and excited line to something to do with links being hyper... dunno.

Comment: This is the first answer that I got right and first! Woo!

Comment: Gratz man, I greatly appreciate the hyperlinks are hyper links simplicity.

Answer (score 5):

> Your heart

Because:

Ideally if you pressure me I will not break,

> Hopefully our relationships grow stronger under pressure and do not fall apart

alas, my weakness seems to come at my weakest.

> Weak or cowardly people are faint of heart

But if you truly press me I will show you the way,

> "Follow your heart"

However afterwards I may be a little flushed.

> If we follow our hearts we may end up flushing

Comment: Reasonable answer, I think the third line ignores the first half sort of, the second line is a reasonable interpretation but seems sort of recursively defining weak as weak (or making a potentially false statement about correlation between courage and physical strength) and the fourth line... well I see what you are getting at there. I like the answer, I just feel it my job to explain why I don't think this quite works.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be:

> A pipe?

Ideally if you pressure me I will not break,

> Self-explanatory.

alas, my weakness seems to come at my weakest.

> A weak point in a pipe can cause the whole thing to be useless.

But if you truly press me I will show you the way,

> High pressure within a pipe causes the contents to move through it.

However afterwards I may be a little flushed.

> Clearing a pipe is "flushing" it.

Comment: Wow, this fits really well... uh... good thing I added another verse? this one actually convinces me my initial was too broad.

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> A glowstick?

Ideally if you pressure me I will not break,

> A glowstick takes some force to light, you can usually bend the outer casing a bit before the glass (or whatever it is nowadays) within breaks.

alas, my weakness seems to come at my weakest.

> A glowstick's 'weakness' is the glass vial within, which is much more brittle than the surrounding plastic.

But if you truly press me I will show you the way,

> If you push hard enough the glass breaks and the glowstick will light up.

However afterwards I may be a little flushed.

> You can't turn a glowstick off, and they often continue to glow after they are no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have two thoughts - one seems to fit for the first half and the other for the second half. I'll post here to see if others can build off of this.

First two lines:

> An egg seems to fit these. Ideally an egg will not break while just squeezing it, but it's weakness is at the widest point - it's "weakest" area.

Second two lines:

> This seems to fit some kind of button. Like an elevator button? If you press it, it should show you the way to the floor you want to go to, and it might get "flushed" - elevator buttons light up when you press them.

Answer (score 0):

> Pressure Cooker

Not sure

> Ideally if you pressure me I will not break,

It will never break on pressure..

> alas, my weakness seems to come at my weakest.

Its weakest part is its sealing ring ..

> But if you truly press me I will show you the way,

if we continuously press the steam vent then tube valve will be broken ..

> However afterwards I may be a little flushed.

then we there will no other way except flushing and fitting a new valuve

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

> Missing

Because

> It says so in the title! The description of the riddle is irrelevant.

Comment: Next step : explain how your answer fit with the riddle